# Draw boxes on edges labels with Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout

Tags: c#

Somebody knows how i can draw the edges labels in a box with this library?

I am using it in C#.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, the Edge object has a propertie called "LabelText" (here is where the Edges label is saved) but i don´t know exactly where it is painted in the graph and neither see how i can draw a box in the label.

Answer (score 0):

If someone have the same problem, i have found a solution. The solution is to modify the Draw class, concretelly the DrawStringInRectCenter method.

I have get as parameter a Graphics and a DObject objects, then i cast if the DOBject is a DNode or DEdge. In case of been DEdge i call DrawRectangle, FillRectangle and DrawString in such order, with the aim of make a box with white background, black border and black label.